# How to project correctly Copernicus VCI product

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I have downloaded time series data of the VCI product from the Copernicus Land Services, which they are in h5 format. The data set covers the African continent.

It is known that the h5 files have an issue with their projection, when someone tries to import them in a spatial analysis software.

What I'm trying to do is to first pass the projection (EPSG:4326) using gdal.warp in python and create a netcdf file which will contain all these data.

Following is the code in python

```
import gdal
wOptions = gdal.WarpOptions(
    dstSRS= "EPSG: 4326",
    outputBounds=(60, -40, -30, 40)
)
dataproj = gdal.Warp(
    format="NETCDF",
    destNameOrDestDS= "Test.nc",
    srcDSOrSrcDSTab="20160101/g2_BIOPAR_VCI_201601010000_AFRI_PROBAV_V1.0.h5",
    options=wOptions,
)
```

The output is a rotated image.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?